# When a database (or upstream service) timeout occurs, do I send a 503 or 504?

Tags: http

If a website depends on an upstream database or other abstracted service or store - basically most websites known to man - then when the upstream requests dies with a timeout, should I return a 503 or a 504?

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down
>   for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state. Sometimes,
>   this can be permanent as well on test servers.
>
> 504 Gateway Timeout
>
> The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a
>   timely response from the upstream server.

The 504 feels more designed for proxy servers, caches or other web infrastructure, but the 503 is not right either since the service is fine, the current request just happened to die, perhaps a search might have been to broad or something.

So which is 'right' according to HTTP?

Luke

Comment: I think this is a great question, and I'm not really satisfied with the answer given. The question is whether 504 is an appropriate general purpose "timed out" code for application servers. It is true that you can ignore the distinction and just use 500s for many applications, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I guess for me, EJK's opening para confirmed my own thoughts that a 503 is a temporary state and a Retry-After header can be sent. The 504 feels infrastructural. Because the 504 has "Timeout" in its name, it feels appropriate but I think a 503 is. Arguably, you could use any code, as long as the response also contains headers and a payload explaining the situation, which is what EJK alludes to in the last para, though I didn't like the choice of a 500, since for me, that's "unhandled".

Comment: I think what I'm really unsatisfied with is the spec, not EJK's answer :) I do agree with the conclusion that 504 shouldn't be used by anyone but a proxy. I think what bothers me is why this code was included, and why it seemed appropriate for proxies but not for application servers. But that's clearly outside the scope of your question.

Comment: RFC 7231 doesn't make this clear, but in general it is important to distinguish between timeouts (504) and backpressure (503). If a request times out, you often have no way of knowing what state the server was left in (maybe the request succeeded and the server died before returning a reply), though sometimes the proxy can be smart about this given domain knowledge (e.g., databases only suffer this problem on the final COMMIT).

Whereas backpressure generally implies that the request was not applied at all, and is safe to retry. Unfortunately like I said, RFC 7231 doesn't advise either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

503 sounds appropriate if this is a temporary condition that will be resolved simply by waiting.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html states: "*The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay."*

500 also sounds appropriate.  The RFC states: "*The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.*"  An unresponsive database is an exceptional/unexpected case.

IMO, what it comes down to is this: Are you providing an error code that will help callers (i.e. HTTP clients) respond to the situation?  In this case, there is really nothing a client can do other than to try again later.  Given this, I would keep it simple and return 500.  I think clients are more likely to care if the site is available and less likely to care about the specific reason.  Plus fewer response codes makes it easier to code clients.  Again this is just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. I'm trying to avoid the 500 since that's the general case and will invoke an email to support. We view a 500 as truly unexpected and thus an outage or bug in code. Sometimes, when the database is hammered, we get timeouts but they're not something that needs investigating.

Comment: In that case, 503 sounds good.  If the timeouts are infrequent and self-correcting, then 503 most clearly describes the situation.